# Bootstrap form design issues

Tags: bootstrap-modal

In my bootstrap form there is unusual gap between rows though they have similar declarations.Also, select boxes looks bigger than what I see in examples,

Here is the problem,

[image]

Any idea what's wrong ?

Here is the code,

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="content_obsinfo" class="tab-pane active">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="panel-body form-horizontal form-padding">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <!-- BEGIN: Logged By Name -->
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <label for="pro_LoggedByName" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Logged by name</label>
                                        </div>
                                           <div class="col-sm-4">
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pro_LoggedByName" name="pro_LoggedByName" value=""    >                                             </div>
                                           <!-- END: Logged By Name-->
                                           <!-- BEGIN: Manager-->
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <label for="top_Manager" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Manager</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                             <div class="radio">
                                                <label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Manager"   value="Yes">Yes</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Manager"   value="No">No</label>
                                             </div>
                                        </div>
                                          <!-- END: Manager-->
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div> <!-- End of row 1 -->
                                   <div class="row">
                                    <div class="panel-body form-horizontal ">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <!-- BEGIN: Conducted On -->
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <label for="pro_ConductedOn" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Conducted on</label>
                                        </div>
                                           <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="input-group date" id="conductedon">
                                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pro_ConductedOn" name="pro_ConductedOn" value="8-Oct-2015"   >
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" title="Open Calendar"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                            </div>
                                           </div>
                                           <!-- END: Conducted On -->
                                           <!-- BEGIN: Employed By-->
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <label for="top_EmployedBy" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Employed by</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <select  data-placeholder="Select employed by" id="top_EmployedBy" name="top_EmployedBy" class="chosen-select"  >
                                                    <option value=""></option><option  value="Company">Company</option><option  value="Maritime">Maritime</option><option  value="Other">Other</option><option  value="Subcontractor">Subcontractor</option><option  value="Third party">Third party</option>
                                                </select>
                                        </div>
                                          <!-- END: Employed By-->
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div> <!-- End of row 2 -->
                                   <div class="row">
                                    <div class="panel-body form-horizontal ">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <!-- BEGIN: Confidentiality   -->
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <label for="pro_Confidentiality" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Confidentiality</label>
                                        </div>
                                           <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                  <div class="radio">
                                                <label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="pro_Confidentiality"   value="Public">Public</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="pro_Confidentiality"   value="Private">Private</label>
                                                  </div>
                                           </div>
                                           <!-- END: Confidentiality   -->
                                           <!-- BEGIN: Job Position-->
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <label for="top_JobPosition" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Job position</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <select  data-placeholder="Select Job position" id="top_JobPosition" name="top_JobPosition" class="chosen-select"  >
                                             <option value=""></option><option  value="Administration">Administration</option><option  value="Catering">Catering</option><option  value="Client">Client</option><option  value="Communication">Communication</option><option  value="Deck hand">Deck hand</option><option  value="Deck office">Deck office</option><option  value="Drivers">Drivers</option><option  value="Engineer / electrician">Engineer / electrician</option><option  value="Gun mechanic">Gun mechanic</option><option  value="Laborers">Laborers</option><option  value="Maintenance">Maintenance</option><option  value="Management">Management</option><option  value="Mechanic">Mechanic</option><option  value="Navigator">Navigator</option><option  value="Observer">Observer</option><option  value="Other">Other</option><option  value="Pilot / aviator">Pilot / aviator</option><option  value="Processing">Processing</option><option  value="Safety - HSE / medic">Safety - HSE / medic</option><option  value="Shore">Shore</option><option  value="Subcontractor">Subcontractor</option><option  value="Support vessel crew">Support vessel crew</option><option  value="Technician">Technician</option>
                                        </select>
                                        </div>
                                          <!-- END: Job Position-->
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div> <!-- End of row 3 -->
                            </div>
                       </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

When I inspect first and second rows,clearly see the difference

[image]
[image]

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle recreating the issue?

Comment: you are using 2 different classes for `input` and `select` either use same classes or it's just padding issue of  `select` element, reduce it's padding or try like this `class="chosen-select form-control"` in `<select>` and see if this fixes it

Answer (score 0):

Another CSS in the project maybe?

row inside col-sm?

row inside row?

Comment: Nah, Using standard nifty.css and boostrap-min.css